# Object creation events in ServiceStack's OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I need to set an event handler on objects that get instantiated by OrmLite, and can't figure out a good way to do it short of visiting every Get method in a repo (which obviously is not a good way).

To give some background - say I have a class User, which is pulled from database; it also implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I want to assign a handler to that event. Having it auto-populated from Funq would be ideal, but of course OrmLite doesn't ask Funq to hydrate the new object.

So I'm stuck.

Any hints in a right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there some reason using the constructor won't work?

Comment: If the constructor won't work, I think you might be better off using another ORM. OrmLite isn't really designed with this extensibility point in mind.

Comment: Constructors won't work, as they should have no knowledge of event handlers. I can in theory just hardcode the handlers, but this is a bad choice on many levels.

Comment: Generally, I'd agree that ctors "should" have no knowledge of event handlers. But in this case it might just be a solution to your problem. If you absolutely cannot go that route, I would suggest using another ORM solution then. OrmLite is designed to be as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're mixing in presentation logic with your data access logic. If I was in your position I would not attempt to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a model (such as your User class). Instead I would create a `ViewModel` and place the databinding logic there ([MVVM Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)).

Having `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the data model is not quite logical when you get down to it. If I were to update the database record it would not fire this event for example (but the property *has* changed). It makes a lot more sense on a ViewModel.

Beyond solving your original issue it also makes building complex screens a lot easier by letting you aggregate, compose, and filter data for display purposes. If you need to pull in information from your database, a RSS feed, a stock ticker web API, and twitter you can do so in your ViewModel.

```
public class User
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public UserViewModel(User user)
    {
        _name = user.Name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

*Small Note: This answer was written in the context of display data on a screen with a ViewModel, however, the same concept applies to observing model changes for any purpose.*

Comment: The issue I was having is not an implementation of INotify (though implementing it on a derived class instead of a model itself would probably be cleaner), but on assigning an event handler. Ideally I would have an OnObjectCreated hook in OrmLite and use that to manipulate an object; another option would be to assign it in Get... methods of repo, which isn't hard or necessarily bad, but feels like code repetition. I think sometimes its OK to spend an hour for research to find a way to save yourself 15 minutes of work :)

Comment: This is not longer a requirement, actually, but the question still stands. I guess if I really want it I'll just need to fork the OrmLite and then do a pull request.